Obtaining the residues of $\frac {(z-1)^2} {(e^z - 1)^3}$
I want to calculate the residues of $$f(z) = \frac {(z-1)^2} {(e^z - 1)^3}.$$ I already know that the isolated singularities are of the form $2\pi i \cdot \mathbb Z$, and that they are poles of order $3$. I also know the general formula to calculate these residues, but computing the second derivative needed for the mentioned formula seems much too tiresome, so there's probably a better method. I think that maybe a Laurent-Expansion can do the trick, but I don't know how to obtain it in this case.

How about shifting the variable z by 2⋅n first, and then Taylor expand ?

Computing a second derivative is clearly less cumbersome than determining an awkward Laurent expansion in that case.

Let $z = 2 n \pi i + h$ where $n \in \mathbb {Z}$. Then
$$\begin{align} {\left( z - 1 \right)}^{2} & = {\left( 2 n \pi i - 1 + h \right)}^{2} \\ & = {\left( 2 n \pi i - 1 \right)}^{2} + 2 \left( 2 n \pi i - 1 \right) h + {h}^{2}, \end{align}$$
and
$$\begin{align} \frac {1}{{\left( {e}^{z} - 1 \right)}^{3}} & = \frac {1}{{\left( {e}^{h} - 1 \right)}^{3}} \\ & = \frac {1}{{\left( h + {h}^{2} / \, 2 + {h}^{3} / \, 6 + \mathcal {O} \left( {h}^{4} \right) \right)}^{3}} \\ & = \frac {1}{{h}^{3}} \cdot \frac {1}{{\left( 1 + h / 2 + {h}^{2} / \, 6 + \mathcal {O} \left( {h}^{3} \right) \right)}^{3}} \\ & = \frac {1}{{h}^{3}} \cdot \frac {1}{1 + 3 h / 2 + 5 {h}^{2} / \, 4 + \mathcal {O} \left( {h}^{3} \right)} \\ & = \frac {1}{{h}^{3}} \cdot \left( 1 - \frac {3 h}{2} + {h}^{2} + \mathcal {O} \left( {h}^{3} \right) \right) \\ & = \frac {1}{{h}^{3}} - \frac {3}{2 {h}^{2}} + \frac {1}{h} + \mathcal {O} \left( 1 \right), \end{align}$$
so
$$\begin{align} {\xi}_{n} & = \text {Res} \left( \left. \frac {{\left( z - 1 \right)}^{2}}{{\left( {e}^{z} - 1 \right)}^{3}} \, \right| z = 2 n \pi i \right) \\ & = h \cdot \bigg( \frac {1}{{h}^{3}} \cdot {h}^{2} - \frac {3}{2 {h}^{2}} \cdot 2 \left( 2 n \pi i - 1 \right) h + \frac {1}{h} \cdot {\left( 2 n \pi i - 1 \right)}^{2} \bigg) \\ & = 1 - \frac {3}{2} \cdot 2 \left( 2 n \pi i - 1 \right) + {\left( 2 n \pi i - 1 \right)}^{2} \\ & = \boxed {5 - 4 {n}^{2} {\pi}^{2} - 10 n \pi i}. \end{align}$$
${\xi}_{n}$ is the residue of the given function in the complex plane at $z = 2 n \pi i$.

$$
{1 \over \left(3 - 1\right)!}\lim_{z\ \to\ 2n\pi{\rm i}}{{\rm d}^{2} \over {\rm d}z^{2}}
\left[\left(z - 2n\pi{\rm i}\right)^{3}\left(z - 1\right)^{2} \over \left({\rm e}^{z} - 1\right)^{3}\right]\ \mbox{where}\ n = 0, \pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 3,\ldots
$$

Yes, that is the formula I also know of. I hoped I could avoid it, as the second derivative becomes quite large, but maybe I just have to endure it.

@Minerva Maybe later I’ll try your idea. Thanks.

I guess the user @Simon already developed your initial idea..
